# Count all values of an array that are between 0 and 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there an effective way to count all the values in a numpy array which are between 0 and 1?

I know this is easily countable with a for loop, but that seems pretty inefficient to me.  I tried to play around with the `count_nonzero()` function but I couldn't make it work the way I wanted.

Greetings

Comment: Could you at least post the code you've came up with so far ?

Comment: @Origine I felt like it would be more confusing than helping because there are only a bunch of variables that don't make much sense of its own.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick and easy method is to use the `logical_and()` function, which returns a boolean mask array.  Then simply use the `.sum()` function to sum the `True` values.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, .1, .2, .3, 1, 2])

np.logical_and(a>0, a<1).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> 3
```

Example 2:

Or, if you'd prefer a more 'low-level' (non-helper function) approach, the `&` logical operator can be used:

```
((a > 0) & (a < 1)).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be one way. You can easily replace `<=` and `>=` with strict inequalities as per your wish.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randn(3,3)
>>> a
array([[-2.17470114,  0.59575531,  0.06795138],
       [-0.57380035,  0.05663369,  1.12636801],
       [ 0.55363332, -0.04039947,  1.14837819]])
>>> inds1 = a >= 0
>>> inds2 = a <= 1
>>> inds = inds1 * inds2
>>> inds
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
>>> inds.sum()
4
```